# Trouble installing video card (software) on a new build

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, build

I'm trying to install my AMD Radeon 6970 graphics card onto my new build, but for some reason I can't get the computer to recognize it. I downloaded the driver off the internet, since the card did not come with a CD of any sort. Here is the site I got it off of ([AMD Radeon 6970 Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx)) I cannot figure out how to get it to recognize the card...any ideas? I can offer more information if you tell me what you need. Thank you!!

Specs: Mobo- ASUS P8Z68-V LX

UPDATE: I can get it to recognize a "Standard VGA Adapter"...but that's when I'm using a DVI cord.

Comment: Are you using Windows Xp/Vista/7/8 or Linux? Do you have the power cables plugged into the card? Are they working? How many PCIE x16 slots do you have? Have you dried a different slot?

Comment: wWindows 7 64 bit. Well, it didnt have power. Whoops! But even after I have plugged it in, I can't get any display on the monitor. Before, I was running it from the mobo using VGA, and I got a signal. Now, even if I try using VGA from the mobo, nothing. DVI from the card doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be disabled in the BIOS. Try looking in there to see if you can find it. If it's not there then you might not be getting enough power to it.

Comment: how do I get back to the BIOS after I'm booted up? I can't seem to get to it in the boot sequence

Comment: You can only get into it when you are booting up. What motherboard are you using?

Comment: ASUS P8Z68-V LX

Comment: How many watts is your PSU?

Comment: 650 watts. should be plenty

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.ehow.com/how_6804375_disable-onboard-graphics-card-bios.html

Comment: You have the 6-pin power connector plugged into it correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4007/discussion-between-tomsawyer95-and-peter-maxwell)